# working with javascript and php while loop

Tags: javascript, php

i want to update rooms rate which is shown on screen shot. when i click on edit room rate it hide existing button and show text box containing existing room value . when i fetched this data using while loop in php it works only on first element. please help me

```
        used javascript as bellow



<script>
                function hide_editbtn()
                {
                var rmrate = document.getElementsByClassName("roomrate"); 

                for(var i = 0; i < rmrate.length; i++){

                rmrate[i].style.display = "none"; 
                rmrate[i].disabled = true; 
                }

                var updbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("updateratebtn"); 
                for(var i = 0; i < updbtn.length; i++){

                updbtn[i].style.display = "none"; 
                rmrate[i].disabled = true;
                }
                }


                function show_editbtn()
                {
                var rmratelink = document.getElementsByClassName("roomratelink"); 

                for(var i = 0; i < rmratelink.length; i++){

                    (function(index){
                    rmratelink[i].onclick = function(){

                        document.getElementById("roomrate").style.display="block";
                        document.getElementById("roomrate").disabled = false;



                    }    
                    })(
                }
                }

                </script>

Used html Content as bellow 

<div class="card-stacked order-sm-1 newelmnt">
            <div class="card-body pt-sm-0 pb-0 px-0 pr-sm-6 pr-md-8">
            <p> &nbsp; </p>
            <h3 class="card-title font-weight-normal text-truncate elconnt">
            Ac Room
            </h3>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline price mb-1">
            <span class="d-block text-primary font-weight-500 display-5 mr-1">Rs.<label id="hotelroomrate">1500</label> &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="btn-group-toggle roomratelink" data-toggle="buttons" onclick="show_editbtn()" id="roomratelink" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-primary mb-2">
            <input type="checkbox"> Edit Room Rate
            </label>
            </span> 
            </span>
            <label class="sr-only" for="user-name">&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control roomrate" id="roomrate" aria-describedby="user-name" placeholder="Modify Room Rate" style="width:180px;padding-right:10px;"/> &nbsp;  &nbsp;
            <span class="btn-group-toggle updateratebtn" data-toggle="buttons" id="updateratebtn" >
            <label class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-2" style="background:#512da8;color:#fff;margin-top:5px;">
            <input type="checkbox"> Submit
            </label>
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbucU.png)

i want to update rooms rate which is shown on screen shot. when i click on edit room rate it hide existing button and show text box containing existing room value . when i fetched this data using while loop in php it works only on first element. please help me

Comment: You have syntax errors. May you make sure that your code is a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the listener because you just wanna show the buttons.
Second, use class instead of an ID for the elements. IDs are unique. So when you loop it only the first occurence will be handled.
Make the #roomrate ID a class .roomrate.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < rmratelink.length; i++){
     let btn = rmratelink[i].getElementsByClassName('roomrate')[0];
     btn.style.display="block";
     btn.disabled = false; 
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for reply. getting btn variable value as undefined so btn.style.display="block"; so text box not showing

Comment: You could also try  function show_editbtn(){ 
   let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('roomrate');
   btns.forEach(function(i){
       i.style.display="block";
       i.disabled = false; 
   })
 }